# FFmpeg image sequence with certain durations combined into a video

Tags: linux, windows, image, ffmpeg

Let's say I have a bunch of images and different float durations. I want to combine the images with the said durations so that they have the right amount of screentime. This is what I have exactly:

I have a bunch of images in a directory like this:

```
image001.png
image002.png
image003.png
...
```

I have all durations stored in a text file "durations.txt" where each line number corresponds with image index:

```
3.445677
2.213412
7.43234
...
```

I found a [image sequence page on wikibooksforum](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence) where you can set each duration with frames shown with something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i image-%3d.jpg -vf "zoompan=d=25+'50*eq(in,3)'+'100*eq(in,5)'" test.mp4
```

But this gets really long and if I have like a hundred images with all different durations, how can I comibine them effectively? Can I read the durations directly from durations.txt?

Comment: unclear how any of the timing data is meant to be transposed into `zoompan=d=25...` . Can you edit your Q to show at least one correct invocation with your sample data? You **can** process from your list, but you'll need to write a small program to generate the correct command line arguments (one at a time). I'm no expert (at all) for `ffmpeg`, but I'd bet you need to use `image%03d.jpg` instead. (change `3` to `4` if your highest number is > 999). Good luck.